# Return list of type DBSet to a view in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to convert a list of type dbset to a view in mvc4. below is my code:

```
        public ActionResult List()
    {
        AuthorContext oauthorContext = new AuthorContext();
        return View(oauthorContext.Authors);
    }
```

The error I am getting is:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`, but this dictionary requires a model item
>   of type 'AuthorContext'.

(Here AuthorContext is of type DbContext)

Comment: Change to `return View(oauthorContext);` or in your View change `@model AuthorContext` to `@model IEnumerable<Author>`.

Comment: thats works and how to iterate the items in view?

Comment: `foreach (var author in Model) { ... }`